# Cohomology of Higman group with coefficient in the group ring

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

This question may be very easy, feel free to close it.
Let $G$ be the Higman group (in particular it has the homology of a trivial group).

Let $S=\mathbb ZG$ be the group ring with integral coefficients $\mathbb Z$.

I’m wondering about the Ext groups

$$ \operatorname{Ext}^{i}_{S}(\mathbb Z,S) $$ where $ \mathbb Z$, $S$ are seen as left $S$-modules in the obvious way.

What are they? As far as I understand the only nontrivial Ext group is  when $n=2$. All other groups are trivial. Moreover the $\operatorname{Ext}^2 $ group is naturally a right $S$-module (and the underlying abelian group has an infinite rank). So the precise question should be: what is the $S$-module $\operatorname{Ext}^{2}_{S}(\mathbb Z,S)$?

Comment: Just for memory, this is usually denoted $H^i(G,\mathbf{Z}G)$. For $n=1$ and $G$ the Higman group this is trivial (the Higman group is 1-ended). For $n=2$ triviality is related to being simply connected at infinity. I don't know if Higman's group has been studied by this angle.

Comment: Note that the Higman group was proved to be aspherical by Baumslag-Dyer-Heller and so $H^n(G,\mathbb ZG)=0$ for $n>2$.

Comment: Should "the $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ group is naturally right $S$-modules" be "the $\operatorname{Ext}^2$ group is naturally a right $S$-module"?

Comment: Further observations: Since $G$ is of type FP there are isomorphisms $H^i(G;M)\cong H^i(G;S)\otimes_S M$ for any $S$-module $M$. In particular (taking $M=\mathbb{Z}$) we see that $H^2(G;S)$ is a transitive, and therefore simple, $S$-module.

Comment: Also for this $G$ we have $H^2(G;S)\cong H^2(G;IG)$, by the augmentation exact sequence $0\to IG\to S\to \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $H^2(G;S)\otimes_S IG\cong H^2(G;S)$. This leads me to guess that $H^2(G;S)\cong IG$. (Further evidence for this is that $IG\otimes_S IG \cong IG^2\cong IG$, since in general $IG/IG^2$ is isomorphic to the abelianisation of $G$.) I wasn't able to prove this, however.

Comment: @MarkGrant it sounds very plausible what you are suggesting! Will be happy if you can find out the final result ! Thnaks

Comment: I've thought about this a little bit more and I retract my guess. Once one realizes that $M\otimes_S IG\cong M$ for *any* transitive $S$-module (since $M/MIG\cong H_0(G;M)$) the evidence in favour of $IG$ evaporates.

Comment: Also, Higman's group can be decribed as an iterated amalgam of Baumslag-Solitar groups. One can find results on the "dualizing module" $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}G)$ of an amalgam $G=G_1\ast_S G_2$ of duality gorups, and the dualizing module of a one-relator group, in Bieri's notes https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/bieri.pdf (see e.g Proposition 9.15 and Exercise at the end of Section 9.5). This suggests the answer is likely to be complicated.